Fetching Is done perfectly in localhost but not in deployed app
Issue with Fetching Data in Deployed Vercel App but Works on Localhost
I'm facing an issue with fetching data in my React application. Here's a simplified version of the code I'm using:
useEffect(() => {
  async function fetchData() {
    const res = await fetch("/api/flowers/getTopThreeData");
    const data = await res.json();

    setRosePetalGarlands(data.rosePetalGarlands);
    setJasmineGarlands(data.jasmineGarlands);
    setDecoration(data.decoration);
  }

  fetchData();
}, []);


Localhost: This code works perfectly fine on my local development server. The API endpoint /api/flowers/getTopThreeData returns the expected data, and everything functions as intended.

Deployed on Vercel: After deploying the app to Vercel, the same code doesn't seem to fetch the data. I checked the Network tab in the browser's DevTools, and it shows that the request is either failing or not fetching the expected data.


Request for Help
What could be causing this issue only in the deployed environment on Vercel? Is there something specific to Vercel's deployment setup that I might be missing?

What I've Tried

Checked Relative Path: I'm aware that using relative paths could cause issues, but other fetch requests in the same app using relative paths work fine even in the deployed environment.
Cache Settings: I tried using no-cache to bypass any potential caching issues, but this didn't solve the problem.

Additional Info

Environment: The issue is specifically with the deployed version on Vercel, while it works without any issues on localhost.
Other Fetches: Similar fetch requests are working fine on both localhost and the deployed server, which makes this issue puzzling.


In order to further investigate the problem try to replace const data = await res.json(); with const text = await res.text(); console log(text);. What do you see in the console then?

"failing" how? "not fetching the expected data"... so what does it return instead?

Can you tell where is your API running? Because in fetch you need to specify whole url example - https://example.com/api/flowers/getTopThreeData

hey @NehJain i did put the full url

@Phil it’s currently returning the data of the last commit’s timestamp from the database.

Have you added proxy for base url?
If yes, that might be the issue. You need to add base url to .env and use it like below:
useEffect(() => {
  const BASE_URL = process.env.BASE_URL;
  async function fetchData() {
    const res = await fetch(`${BASE_URL}/api/flowers/getTopThreeData`);
    const data = await res.json();

    setRosePetalGarlands(data.rosePetalGarlands);
    setJasmineGarlands(data.jasmineGarlands);
    setDecoration(data.decoration);
  }

  fetchData();
}, []);


Question is tagged with [tag:next.js]. The API and frontend are both the same host with the backend provided by either API Routes or Route Handlers

Hey! I did try this and it's still not working, i even tried directly using the url of the deployed website, but it's not working, can supposively any other problem?

@ashikpy can you share you base url of Vercel & the screenshot of api error from network tab?
